# Angular JS: Write array of objects to $scope variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm doing an application which takes API from iTunes and displays it in my HTML. But in  *$scope.bands* variable always writes only one note.

my code

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="band in bands">
            {{band.artist}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    let app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(" https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=The+Beatles").then(function(response) {
  let jsonData = []; 
  for (let i = 0; i < response.data.resultCount; i++) {
    $scope.bands = [{
        artist:response.data.results[i].artistName,
        track:response.data.results[i].trackName,
        collection:response.data.results[i].collectionName,
        genre:response.data.results[i].primaryGenreName,
        image:response.data.results[i].artworkUrl100
    }];


  }
  }, function(response) {
  $scope.content = "ERROR:Something went wrong";});});


</script>
```

Please explain me, why it doesn't work properly!

Thank you in advance

Comment: `$scope.bands =` is overwriting the array with each loop iteration. Declare `$scope.bands = []` outside the loop, then use `$scope.bands.push({});` to add to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hadn't defined the value $scope.bands yet

Checkout the scope article for more info:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Also you need to push to an array:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Try this:

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="band in bands">
            {{band.artist}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    let app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(" https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=The+Beatles").then(function(response) {
  let jsonData = []; 
  $scope.bands = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < response.data.resultCount; i++) {
    $scope.bands.push({
        artist:response.data.results[i].artistName,
        track:response.data.results[i].trackName,
        collection:response.data.results[i].collectionName,
        genre:response.data.results[i].primaryGenreName,
        image:response.data.results[i].artworkUrl100
    });


  }
  }, function(response) {
  $scope.content = "ERROR:Something went wrong";});});


</script>
```

Also you could refactor slightly:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < response.data.resultCount; i++) {
    let currentData = response.data.results
    $scope.bands.push({
        artist:currentData[i].artistName,
        track:currentData[i].trackName,
        collection:currentData[i].collectionName,
        genre:currentData[i].primaryGenreName,
        image:currentData[i].artworkUrl100
    });
```

Comment: @Vadim - Glad to help :-)

Don't forget to accept an answer